# Java process NOT shutting down gracefully

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ec2, exception

I have a long Java process running in a docker container. It gets shutdown by the kernel as shown in the logs here under. It fails without OutOfMemory Java Error or Exception. I went into dmesg to figure out that this was indeed shut down by the kernel.How can I make sure that this exception is logged and the process gracefully shuts down?  I want to catch that error and throw an application specific exception. 
Should I use UnCaughtErrorHandler (Java feature) and and then throw my application specific exception in there?

```
demsg -T | grep java Wed Feb 20 04:09:23 2019] [ 3281] 503 3281 654479 38824 145 0 0 java [Wed Feb 20 04:09:23 2019] [11369] 0 11369 3253416 1757772 4385 0 0 **java [Wed Feb 20 04:09:24 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 11369 (java) score 914 or sacrifice child [Wed Feb 20 04:09:24 2019] Killed process 11369 (java) total-vm:13013664kB, anon-rss:7031088kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB**
```

Comment: I'm assuming the container sees that it's out of memory before the JVM does. Why don't you set the maximum memory of the JVM to something lower?

Comment: Should I not increase the memory limit of JVM to accommodate the needs of my process. Lets say even after the best efforts, my JVM gets shut-down, that is fine.But I want to throw my Application Specific exception when that happens . @jacobG

Comment: I don't think that would make sense; if the container is seeing that you're out of memory before the JVM does, then increasing the memory limit of the JVM won't change anything. It's the container that you need to worry about

Comment: Hmm, should I not increase the memory limit of container? Lets say may be container can use only X GB of RAM as of now. If I increase it to X+ delta, then my JVM process which lies inside the container can use that? Isn't it. Am I missing some thing. Sorry. @JacobG

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I don't know anything about your application, so I can't recommend much, but you should try to give your application ample memory that it requires. If it's allowed to run out memory for some reason, then you might be able to catch the `Throwable`.

Comment: Maybe you can monitor the RAM usage from Java using `Runtime`? So that if your resource usage reaches a threshold level you can either log warnings or gracefully shut down from within the app